# Absolutely cannot delete a record(entire row) from Access DB in my code

Tags: vb.net

I have deleted the bulk of my original posting since what I say below has gotten me a step closer. But I jumped the gun a little.
Below is where I'm at and I have a new problem but I think it's minor but can't seem to see where it is. It's a concurrency violation and as I understand this error I am apparently trying to save to the database twice but I can't see where I am doing this. I only call the update method once during an add record save. So what's happening is I add a record then save it then I delete that record just to see if the record is being deleted by viewing it in MS Access, it works the record is gone. Then I add the record again to see if it comes back and I get the error.

One thing to note is I am using a BindingNav which determines the current record count/position that I want to delete and I said in my original post that it's more likely than not that the last record will be the one deleted due to input mistake.

Update:
I canna believe it !!! I nailed it ... figures after I post this ridiculous plea for help I get inspiration and find exactly what I needed or was looking for. Here's the code that finally works: (or so I thought)

```
    Dim row_to_delete As String, Current_Record As Integer

    Current_Record = All649_BS.Count
    row_to_delete = "DELETE FROM [All 649] WHERE(DrawNumber = " & Current_Record & ")"

    All649_BS.RemoveCurrent()
    All_649TableAdapter.Adapter.DeleteCommand.CommandText = row_to_delete

    Try
        All_649TableAdapter.Delete()
        ErrorMsgs.Text = ("Update successful")

    Catch ex As Exception

        ErrorMsgs.Text = ("Update failed")

    End Try

End Sub
```

Here is the code for the add record and save sections.

```
Private Sub Add_Rcrd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Add_Rcrd.Click

    ErrorMsgs.Text = ""

    WkDay = All649_BS.Current(10)
    All649_BS.AddNew()                'Add the new enry

    DrawNumber.Text = All649_BS.Count
    Actual_Count.Text = All649_BS.Count

    If WkDay = "WED" Then
        Weekday.Text = "SAT"
    Else
        Weekday.Text = "WED"
    End If

    DateField.Focus()

End Sub

Private Sub Save_Record_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Save_Record.Click

    Dim a1 As Int32
    Dim b2 As Int32
    Dim c3 As Int32
    Dim d4 As Int32
    Dim e5 As Int32
    Dim f6 As Int32

    'Check for entry errors

    If DateField.Text = "" Then              ' Check to see a date was enetered
        ErrorMsgs.Text = "Please enter a date !"
        DateField.Text = ""
        DateField.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Pos1.Text = "" Or Pos1.Text < 1 Or Pos1.Text > 49 Then   ' Check 1st number entry
        ErrorMsgs.Text = "You have forgotten to enter 1st number or the number is invalid !"
        Pos1.Text = ""
        Pos1.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Pos2.Text = "" Or Pos2.Text < 1 Or Pos2.Text > 49 Then   ' Check 2nd number entry
        ErrorMsgs.Text = "You have forgotten the 2nd number or the number is invalid !"
        Pos2.Text = ""
        Pos2.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Pos3.Text = "" Or Pos3.Text < 1 Or Pos3.Text > 49 Then   ' Check 3rd number entry
        ErrorMsgs.Text = "You have forgotten the 3rd number or the number is invalid !"
        Pos3.Text = ""
        Pos3.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Pos4.Text = "" Or Pos4.Text < 1 Or Pos4.Text > 49 Then   ' Check 4th number entry
        ErrorMsgs.Text = "You have forgotten the 4th number or the number is invalid !"
        Pos4.Text = ""
        Pos4.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Pos5.Text = "" Or Pos5.Text < 1 Or Pos5.Text > 49 Then   ' Check 5th number entry
        ErrorMsgs.Text = "You have forgotten the 5th number or the number is invalid !"
        Pos5.Text = ""
        Pos5.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Pos6.Text = "" Or Pos6.Text < 1 Or Pos6.Text > 49 Then   ' Check 6th number entry
        ErrorMsgs.Text = "You have forgotten the 6th number or the number is invalid !"
        Pos6.Text = ""
        Pos6.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Bonus.Text = "" Or Bonus.Text < 1 Or Bonus.Text > 49 Then   ' Check 6th number entry
        ErrorMsgs.Text = "You have forgotten the Bonus number or the number is invalid !"
        Bonus.Text = ""
        Bonus.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    End If

    a1 = Val(Pos1.Text)
    b2 = Val(Pos2.Text)
    c3 = Val(Pos3.Text)
    d4 = Val(Pos4.Text)
    e5 = Val(Pos5.Text)
    f6 = Val(Pos6.Text)
    Sumbox.Text = a1 + b2 + c3 + d4 + e5 + f6

    Try

        Validate()
        All649_BS.EndEdit()
        All_649TableAdapter.Update(All649_DataSet)
        ErrorMsgs.Text = ("Update successful")

    Catch ex As Exception

        ErrorMsgs.Text = ("Update failed")

    End Try

    All649_BS.MoveLast()
    All649Nav.Focus()

End Sub
```

So apparently somewhere in this code update is being done twice. Remember I add a record then immediately delete it to see if it was working and it does then a add that record again and get the error.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: `Current_Record` from a bindingsource(?) `Count` isnt going to work.  You need to supply the value for the of `DrawNumber` (?) of the record you want to delete.

Comment: Post an answer and mark it as the accepted answer, so this question doesn't show up as if it's unanswered and people waste their time reading through it.

Comment: That code will still only work by coincidence (an accident of the data).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for replying I did find a solution. I added this line:
All649_DataSet.AcceptChanges()
after the delete method inside that try catch block and viola !

Now I'm having another issue with the autonumber BS I disabled it and now my record save won't work anymore because my primary key was that and autofilled my first field which is required. With autonumber on that field and deleting record the number sequence messes up. DOH !!!